# Some code is not removed from the code coverage

Tags: c++, qt, code-coverage, lcov

I want to generate a code coverage report for my *Qt/C++* project.

I have a short version with a class inheriting *QObject*:

```
#include <QObject>

class Baba : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Baba();

    void mange(int a);

signals:
    void pouet();
};
```

I first add this compilation flag:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --coverage
QMAKE_LFLAGS += --coverage
```

After executing my tests, I perform the following step:

```
$ gcov main.cpp
$ lcov --capture --directory . --output-file capture.info
$ lcov --remove capture.info "*Qt*.framework*" "*.h" "*Xcode.app*" "*moc_*" --output-file filtered.info
$ genhtml filtered.info --output-directory out
```

Unfortunately I still have coverage for the file `moc_Baba.cpp` despite I added `"*moc_*"` during the remove step.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

After inspecting the [lcov source code](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov), I manage to remove the `moc_*` files by replacing `"*moc_*"` by `"$$OUT_PWD/moc_*"`.